# What is the meaning of having void in the constructor definition?

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
#pragma once

class B
{
public:

    B(void)
    {
    }

    ~B(void)
    {
    }
};
```

I know I can also write this:

```
#pragma once

class B
{
public:

    B()
    {
    }

    ~B()
    {
    }
};
```

What is the purpose of having `void` in the first example?  Is it some type of practice that states the constructor take **zero** parameters?

Comment: i found this discussion pretty interesting back then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540748/void-void-c-and-c

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The two are same, at least in C++. In C, providing an empty pair of parentheses typically means an unspecified parameter list (as opposed to an empty parameter list). C++ does not have this problem.

***How can a correct answer get downvoted so many times? Yet another SO bug?***

Comment: At least you're in the positive. I recently had an accepted (correct) answer that ended up with negative votes.  Disturbing.

Comment: @JaredPar: And I was joking about this too will happen to a colleague a couple of days back. I have 3 accepted answers removed in the last 3 days -- shocking?

Comment: @dirkgently, that is odd.  I think I average about 1 accepted answer removed every 2-3 weeks.  3 in 3 days is definitely high.

Comment: @JaredPar @dirkgently At least you *have* accepted answers. Us low rep folks aren't so lucky. :)

Comment: "The two are same, at least in C++", well, this might be misleading... In C  there are no classes ;)

Answer (score 10):

A long time ago you did something like this in C (my pre-ISO C is rusty :) ):

```
void foo(a, b)
   int a, 
   int b
{
}
```

while C++ was being created the name mangling required the types of the arguments, so for C++ it was changed to:

```
void foo(int a, int b)
{
}
```

and this change was brought forward to C.

At this point, I believe to avoid breaking existing C code this:

```
void foo()
```

and this:

```
void foo(void)
```

meant two very different things, `()` means *do not check for the argument number or type*, and `(void)` means *takes no arguments*.  For C++ `()` meaning *not to check anything* was not going to work so `()` and `(void)` mean the same thing in C++.

So, for C++ `()` and `(void)` were always the same thing.

At least that is how I remember it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

afaik if you pass void into the constructor or any function as the argument it means that the function dosnt take any argument so example a and b are equal. but i am not sure if any of them change the function signature in any way or make it run faster etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that when you use void after the parameters like function():void it is used to indicate that the function does not return a value.