# Implications of typedef void FOO vs. #define FOO void in function signatures

Tags: c++, c, typedef, c-preprocessor

While going through some source code that heavily mixes C and C++, I came across the following (slightly modified to protect the work of the company, the meaning remains the same):

```
/*
 * Typedefs of void are synonymous with the void keyword in C,
 * but not in C++. In order to support the use of MY_VOID
 * in place of the void keyword to specify that a function takes no
 * arguments, it must be a macro rather than a typedef.
 */
#define MY_VOID void
```

What is the difference between `typedef void MY_VOID` and `#define MY_VOID void` in this specific context?

---

I don't believe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540748/void-void-c-and-c) because it asks specifically about the implications in regards to function signatures, rather than a much more general "what's the difference".

Comment: It's well explained here
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130679/typedefs-and-defines

Comment: @Morb: That explains why you'd usually prefer a `typedef` but, as far as I can see, doesn't explain why you can't in this particular case.

Comment: I do not see how this question nor the accepted answer are saying anything different than the earlier question... So I have marked this as a duplicate.

Comment: It is a duplicate.  Although the other question doesn't mention function signatures in the title, that is exactly what the question body concerns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple test program in C++ demonstrates the difference:

```
typedef void VOID;

void f(VOID) {}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

On compilation (as C++), [it gives these error](http://ideone.com/6CPjyf):

```
prog.cpp:5:8: error: '<anonymous>' has incomplete type
 void f(VOID) {}
        ^
prog.cpp:5:12: error: invalid use of 'VOID {aka void}'
 void f(VOID) {}
            ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:9:7: error: too few arguments to function 'void f(<type error>)'
     f();
       ^
prog.cpp:5:6: note: declared here
 void f(VOID) {}
      ^
```

which explains what the comment means in your code. In particular, it seems the typedef `VOID` attempts to be a type *different* from `void`, *when it is used as parameter type*.

Comment: Not really, as a function with VOID as return type is treated just like a normal void function in C++

Comment: @Mints97" *when it is used as parameter type*".

Comment: yup, exactly. I wonder where in the standards are the differences.

Comment: The second `void` in `void f(void)` is not being used as a parameter type! `f` does not take a single parameter of type `void`. Nor could it. It is a syntactic construct to inform the compiler that the function takes no arguments. That is why the `typedef` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for much for this! a standard excerpt would make it even better

Comment: It seems things has been change in C++11, but right now I'm in hurry, so wont update this answer with the spec. **Please see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/540850/415784) in the accepted answer of the duplicate**.

Comment: @Nawaz it's no longer a duplicate, but thank you for your time :) If someone else doesn't do it before me, I might be able to find the time to edit your answer to include this information later. Thanks again!

Comment: @TonkyK: Why would the `#define` work any differently?

Answer (score 5):

The comment explains the difference. Given an alias for `void`:

```
typedef void MY_VOID;
```

If you try to use this instead of `void` to indicate that a function takes no parameters:

```
int f(MY_VOID);
```

C will allow this, but C++ won't.

So, if you really want to make life difficult for yourself by writing code that (a) is valid in both languages and (b) uses an alias for this particular use of `void`, that alias will have to be a macro.

Answer (score 3):

The comment refers to code like this:

```
typedef void my_void_t;
my_void_t foo(my_void_t); // Illegal.
```

With the `#define` it's legal.

Answer (score 1):

An excerpt from the language standards can make everything better!

C99, 6.7.5.3/10:

> The special case of an unnamed parameter of type void as the only item in the list speciﬁes that the function has no parameters.

C++, 8.3.5/2:

> If the parameter-declaration-clause is empty, the function takes no arguments. The parameter list (void) is equivalent to the empty parameter list.

The difference is plain. C has the `void` in question as an unnamed parameter of type `void`, and C++ has the identifier `void`. The former can be `typedef`-ed, the latter can't.

It may be interesting to muse on the reasons for this. Actually, the following is legal in C++, but illegal in C:

```
void fn(int){
}
```

As C++ has the concept of unnamed (anonymous) parameters in function definitions, while C doesn't... Almost.

Actually, one unnamed parameter can be present in a C function definition: one of type `void`.

Which definitely makes little to no sense since there can be no *named* parameter with this type.

Besides making little sense, this definition of `void` in the parameter list could screw up C++'s unnamed parameters, as it would be no different from them. The definition could have been amended to make it a **very-very-very** special case of an unnamed parameter that has no corresponding named parameters and cannot be used with other named or unnamed parameters and is not actually a parameter and...

But I guess that instead of trying to word something as crazy as that, the C++ commitee simply decided to drop the "unnamed-void-type-parameter" stuff completely and go with the "special parameter list". I say good riddance.

And the C standard? It probably retains its weird 6.7.5.3/10 for backward compatibility reasons...

Answer (score -1):

You can use both, they are doing the same thing so the single difference its that using #define you will declare your new type as a macro.

Comment: thank you for trying to answer, however it turns out this is incorrect. :)